# MAGENTO US Tax Settings

Tags: magento, magento-1.8, application-settings

My understanding is that I only have to charge taxes in the state(s) I have a physical presence, in my case that is TX only.

So, I can't seem to set up the tax rates to charge the tax rate for customers in TX but a 0% rate for everywhere else.

Some assistance on the proper settings to accomplish this would be most welcome!  I'm sorta shocked I could not find it on here already . . . but it's sort of hard to word the question  for the search engine to know what I am looking for I guess . ...

Comment: Taxation rules and application configuration are off-topic. I'd suggest a different place to ask but you've omitted to tell us which application you're trying to configure.

Comment: oops sorry, this is Magento.  I don't need the tax laws, just advice on how to get taxes applied for TX but a rate of zero everywhere else.

Comment: You want to post here instead: http://magento.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a Tax Rate for Texas**

1. In your Magento Admin, go to **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Zones & Rates**
2. Click the **Add New Tax Rate** button
3. Fill in the tax rate information for Texas (as of August, 2014, Texas state tax is 8.25%)[image: Tax Rate Information]
4. Click the **Save Rate** button.

**Create a Tax Rule**

1. Go to **Sales > Tax > Manage Tax Rules**
2. Click the **Add New Tax Rule** button.
3. Fill out the Tax Rule information, selecting Texas for the **Tax Rate** option.
   [image: Tax Rule settings]
4. Click the **Save Rule** button

**Assign the Product Tax class to Products**

1. Go to your product edit pages under **Catalog > Manage Products** (click a product to edit)
2. On the **Prices** tab, set the Tax Class to **Taxable Goods** (or whatever tax class you assigned the Texas tax rule to.)
3. Save your product.

Taxes will be applied at the cart only AFTER the customer enters their location (in the estimate shipping & taxes block on the checkout page).  Taxes will also be applied during the checkout process AFTER their address has been entered.

Since the tax rate is applied for Texas, taxes will only be applied when a Texas address is inputted by the customer.

You can configure how Magento handles tax under **System > Configuration > Sales > Tax**

Comment: Not sure which portion of my answer is incorrect and warrants a down-vote.

Comment: Wasn't me that downvoted it, looks like the right answer to me. I had something interferring with it working via another tax rule I was trying to implement.  I deleted everything and started over from scratch and it is all working now. I'd up vote it if I had the reputation.

THanks!